# Python IOError: [Errno 2] when saving captured image

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I am currently doing a motion detection project that captures image when motion is detected using raspberry pi & raspberry pi camera module. The image would then be uploaded to dropbox.

However i am having this error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Motion2017_07_21_07_39_36.png'

This is my code:

```
def TakePicUpload(frame):
    cv2.imwrite('image.png', frame)
```

Comment: What if you set `mode='w'`?

Comment: @CoryMadden i have tried setting mode = 'w'. Still doesnt work

Comment: Try setting it to 'w+'

Comment: @CoryMadden Still have the same error. Would it be better if i post my entire code here?

Comment: @CoryMadden It doesnt fix the error but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A09iD.png)
Either you are pointing to wrong location or may be some libraries may be missing.
I just implemented a part of your code and it is perfectly working.I don't know what u are passing as **frame** .assuming it as image...the code follows.

```
import cv2
import time
frame=cv2.imread("abc.png",1)
timestring = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
face_timestr = 'Motion' + timestring + '.png'
cv2.imwrite(face_timestr, frame)
Facefile = open(face_timestr, mode = "rb")
data = Facefile.read()
```

this is the code edited from your TakePicUpload function.**Check your python version is 2.7.Newer versions like 3.6** shows some problems in **opencv**.